# Запись значения переменных из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

У нас есть файл input.txt, в нем написаны два числа. Первое записано в первой строке, второе - во второй.
Надо записать в переменные x и y числа из первой строки и из второй
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать таковое

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он содержит только текст задания

Comment: @Komdosh, ты много заданий "считать числа в переменные" видел? Их даже сложить не попросили. Это простой вопрос о баховом использовании языка, который является онтопиком.

Comment: @WhiteApfel, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В простом случае это выглядит так:

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
    x = int(file.readline())
    y = int(file.readline())

print(x, y)
```

Каждый вызов метода readline() возвращает последовательно строки из файла.

Также можно получить все строки сразу с помощью метода readlines() и присвоить их переменным:

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
    x, y = [int(line) in line for file.readlines()]

print(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.txt') as file:  # '''\n 1 \n 2 \n 3\n\n\n 4\n 5\n 6 \n\n 7 \n'''
    var_list = filter(str.strip, file)  # (str, ) очистить пробельные символы/пустые линии
    var_list = list(map(int, var_list))  # [int, ]

print(var_list)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
if len(var_list) > 1:
    x, y = var_list[:2]  # [1, 2]
    print(x, y)  # 1 2
```